# MySQL DB migration: change of string length

Tags: python, mysql, alembic

I'm using SQLAlchemy + alembic to manage my database. I had a string field which was 10 characters long and later on found out that it has to be 20. So I updated the model definition.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

When I run `alembic revision --autogenerate`, this was not detected. Now I did read the documentation and suspected that this might not be supported. How do I managed such changes in DB gracefully?

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable optional column type [checking](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.compare_type). 
See [this](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect) for notes on what is checked by default

```
context.configure(
    # ...
    compare_type = True
)
```

Comment: I have the same issue as the questioner but this change didn't actually resolve my issue. I gave an upvote as this is still useful but I don't think adding compare_type = True does identify string columns where the length has been changed.